# The object of UserProifle cannot be saved for ShiroUser

Tags: grails, groovy

I am working on a Grails app and I am trying to tie a ShiroUser with a UserProfile. 
I have two models called ShiroUser and UserProfile. In my ShiroUser:

```
class ShiroUser {
    ... ...
    static hasOne = [profile: UserProfile]
    static constraints = {
       email(nullable: false, blank: false, unique: true)
       profile(nullable: false)
    }
}
```

And in my UserProfile.groovy, I have:

```
class UserProfile {
    ... ...
    static belongsTo = [shiroUser:ShiroUser]

}
```

However, in my ShiroUserController.groovy, when I try to create a new ShiroUser instance, this doesn't work so well. Here's my code:

```
 def create() {
        [shiroUserInstance: new ShiroUser(params), userProfileInstance: new  UserProfile()]
    }
def save() {

        //todo add validation for email and password here.
        def shiroUserInstance = new ShiroUser(params)

        // Create a user profile
        def userProfileInstance = new UserProfile()
        shiroUserInstance.profile.email = params.email
        shiroUserInstance.profile.firstName = params.firstName
        shiroUserInstance.profile.lastName = params.lastName

        if (!userProfileInstance.save(flush: true)){
            render(view: "create", model: [userProfileInstance: userProfileInstance])
            return
        }
        shiroUserInstance.profile = userProfileInstance

        if (!shiroUserInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "create", model: [shiroUserInstance: shiroUserInstance])
            return
        }

        flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'shiroUser.label', default: 'ShiroUser'), shiroUserInstance.id])
        redirect(action: "show", id: shiroUserInstance.id)
    }
```

When I go to my application and try to create a new ShiroUser, the object cannot be saved. I updated the schema before I run the app so it should not be a migration issue. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in this block of code you are assigning `email`, `firstName` and `lastName` to the wrong object:

```
    // Create a user profile
    def userProfileInstance = new UserProfile()
    shiroUserInstance.profile.email = params.email
    shiroUserInstance.profile.firstName = params.firstName
    shiroUserInstance.profile.lastName = params.lastName
```

Try this instead:

```
    // Create a user profile
    def userProfileInstance = new UserProfile()
    userProfileInstance.email = params.email
    userProfileInstance.firstName = params.firstName
    userProfileInstance.lastName = params.lastName
    shiroUserInstance.profile = userProfileInstance
```

You should then be able to get away with just saving `shiroUserInstance` and it should automatically save `userProfileInstance` as well if you have your mapping set up correctly.